# Bind IsChecked of a CheckBox to a method

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to bind the IsChecked property of a checkbox to a custom method?

I created a list of checkboxes bound to a collection of objects. I have a second collection of objects which is a subset of the first one. I'd like to bind the IsChecked porperty of the checkbox to a method that determines if the object is contained in the second list or not

EDIT:

```
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSources}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" 
                              Content="{Binding Name}" 
                              Tag="{Binding Id}"  
                              Margin="0,5,0,0"

                              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: If you're not MVVMing it, then use the [Checked event.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx)

Comment: I have a ViewModel class in the middle. My plan is to use the Checked event to modify data in a DB. I can't figure out how to list the item as checked accordingly.

Comment: Is your CheckBox in a DataTemplate where you have access to the second (subset) collection?

Comment: Can't you turn it around? If the object is added to the second list than set the bool on the first?

Comment: I added the markup of the view. I have another list with a subset of the objects.

Comment: @Clemens I have the checkbox in a DataTemplate. I guess I could the second subset collection if needed.

Comment: I do not wish to offend you but I'm guessing you've got the logic reversed. When you add/update the second you can set the value on the first. Second I notice you are Binding an Id to the Tag of your CheckBox in the template, why? How are you ever going to access that Tag within the DataTemplate? The id is readable through ((MyClass)listbox.SelectedItem).Id or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the checkbox Command property to a ICommand on your model. This means every time the check is changed the command will be invoked.

Example:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" 
                          Content="{Binding Name}" 
                          Tag="{Binding Id}"  
                          Margin="0,5,0,0"
                          Command={Binding CheckBoxChangedCommand}  
                          />
```

Answer (score 2):

You may bind `IsChecked` to both the data object and the subset collection by means of a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) in conjunction with a [multi-value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that converts into a `bool` (or `Nullable<bool>` for `IsChecked`) value:

```
<CheckBox.IsChecked>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectInListConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
        <Binding />
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource SubsetCollection}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.IsChecked>
```

The converter:

```
class ObjectInListConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IList subset = values[1] as IList;
        Nullable<bool> result = subset.Contains(values[0]);
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would I define the ObjectInListConverter as Window.Resource?

Comment: Exactly. And please note that you have to set `Mode="OneWay"` on the MultiBinding.

Comment: How would I actually define my subset list as a Window.Resource (StaticResource)??

Comment: Exactly the same way as any other entry in the resource dictionary, e.g. the ObjectInListConverter. You could perhaps derive a class from `List<MyDataObject>`, call it `MyDataObjectList` and create an instance of that type in the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pop Catalin's answer, you will want to bind IsChecked to a property in the VM and modify that VM property when command is executed.